# I cannot go through a Json with Cakephp collections to extract "only" the last arrays

Tags: arrays, json, cakephp

I have a JSON ( https://api.myjson.com/bins/us5f4 )  I have been trying to go through the array and extract "only" the last Arrays that are under "Obs" in my JSON, here is a picture of the JSON of what I need to extract:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvNEL.jpg

I do not understand how can I make "while" operations with the collections methods of cakephp, I tried combining ->extract and -> last methods and it only shows me the last array, but I need this to be recursive, so I can extract all the last 18 arrays.
This is the code I had so far:

```
$series = $xmlArray['StructureSpecificData']['message:DataSet']['Series'];

$allYears = collection($series)->extract('Obs');

$lastYears = $allYears->last();
```

Comment: `collection($series)->extract('Obs')->toArray()` maybe?

Comment: Hello @ChrisWhite , sorry I tried that but it doesnt make a difference

Comment: try ```$lastInSeries = end($series);``` and test ouput  ```print_r($lastInSeries['Obs'])```

Comment: Hi @Salines , this returns me exactly what my posted code returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `extract` function can take a function as its parameter:

```
$allYears = collection($series)->extract(function ($s) {
    $last = end($s['Obs']);
    return $last['@OBSVALUE'];
})->toArray();
```

Comment: Thanks Greg,  The cakephp documentation do not have that type of information about using a function inside **extract** function, this definitely solved my problem

Comment: From [the docs](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/collections.html#Cake\Collection\Collection::extract): "Finally, if the property you are looking after cannot be expressed as a path, you can use a callback function to return it."